# How to return TADOConnection from COM(type library)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am working on Delphi 7 and i want to share ADO connection object between Different Delphi applications. how to do that using type library?

while creating methods i can return only String / integer / some datatype and i didnt see any TADOConnection. How to return tADOConnection?

[image]

Comment: You can't just make a Delphi class into a COM object.  COM only returns certain types which it supports, and a Delphi class isn't one of them.  On the face of it, what you are trying to do seems far more trouble than it is worth.  Why do you think you need to "share" an AdoConnection across applications?  What benefit do you expect it to provide?

Comment: @MartynA : we have a Base Application which needs to be run all the time. So i want to create a TADOConnection object and connect to DataBase in Base Application and use the same connection in all other applications.

Comment: Do you know about COM "marshalling"?

Comment: @MartynA: No idea :(

Comment: Well, quite.  It is a difficult subject and the thing you are assuming is that some kind of TAdoConnectton-based COM object would allow the connection to be used across processes from a technical standpoint. I don't know the answer to that, but I will post you an answer a bit later which will explain how to find out.

Comment: @MartynA: Thank you very much. i will wait :)

Comment: Do you really have to use COM objects?  Because there might be other ways to share connections like using Dll's, even though it might be a bad idea to share connections across applications.

Comment: You cant share ado connection object across different threads. Share the connection string if you must.

Comment: @kobik : same user uses Same connection string to connect to different applications. is it like Creating new connection for every applications or internally it uses same connection since we are using same connection string?

Comment: Internally it will be using a different connection object with pooling as long as you use the exact connection string.

Comment: @kobik: so when i need to share connection? i mean 
create the connection string and share the same Connection string 
or
create the connection string , connect to database and share the same connection string?

Comment: I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225816/sharing-adoconnectionstring-accross-multiple-applications-delphi

Answer (score 1):

A TAdoConnection, along with all the other TAdoxxx objects defined in AdoDB.PAS,
"sits on top of" and uses objects which are created in Windows' ADO sub-system.
If you look at the D7 source unit AdoInt.Pas, this is a type library import
of C:\PROGRAM FILES\COMMON FILES\SYSTEM\ADO\MSADO15.DLL.  One of the object interfaces
defined in it is _Connection, and it is an instance of this that does all the work
for TAdoConnection.

Some of the interface objects defined in AdoInt.Pas work across process boundaries,
most notably the `RecordSet` object, which is the ADO-level object that intermediates
between the server and the Delphi-side AdoCustomDataset descendants like TAdoQuery,
etc.  There is a chapter on this in David Sceppa's "Programming ADO" book (Microsoft Press)
and I have written a test COM server which makes a RecordSet object available via COM and it works fine.

However, as far as I've been able to establish by experiment, it is not possible to
get a TAdoConnection or its underlying ConnectionObject to work across process
boundaries using COM.

But if what originally motivated your thoughts in this direction was simply the tedium of having to keep setting up AdoConnections in the same way in every new project, personally what I would do is just to derive a custom TAdoConnection descendant which sets the properties you always use in code, and then register it with Delphi so that it shows up on the Component Palette.

Comment: @kobik:  Thanks, but I am not sure those answers are correct, because I have shared a ConnectionObject between AdoConnections in different threads to simplify retrieving a query's results in the background.

Comment: @kobik:  See update, and maybe resist the temptation to say "I  told you so" ;=)