# Sharing ADOConnectionString accross multiple applications-Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am working on Delphi 7, SQL Server 2008 R2 and i am using ADO to connect to database.

**My Connection String:**

**Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TESTDataBase;Data Source=TestDataSource**

when i make my TADOconnection.Connected to True Connectin string is changing it to

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=TESTDataBase;Data Source=TestDataSource; **Use Procedure for Prepare=1;
Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=MYMachineName;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False**

There are more than 10 applications and i am planning to use the same connection string in all applications.
so when i connect to FirstApplcation i am creating ADO Connection string, saving it in registry or some where so i can use the same connection string for other applications also.

Same user can run more than one application(it can be 2 or 3 or 5 applications).

Here i have 3 questions

1)when i need to share connection?

i mean create the connection string and share the same Connection string(write to registry or some where)

or

create the connection string , connect to database and share the same connection string(write to registry or some where)

2) In my application when i get the shared connection string do i need to connect to database again(TADOConnection.Connected= true)? i think i should connect it again, since it is different application :)

3) For all my applications i open connection at application(main form) form show and i will be closing connection at application(main form) form close.So connection will get close only when application closes and TADOCOnnection.KeepConnection = True. is this create performance issues or burden on database server?

Comment: Just keep the needed properties (catalog, server, login details, ...) somewhere (config file, registry, ..) and construct the connectionstring yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shared [`UDL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e(v=vs.71).aspx) file can be good for sharing a connection. Use the *required* properties only for your connection string, i.e:

> Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security
>   Info=False;Initial Catalog=TESTDataBase;Data Source=TestDataSource

Don't worry about the extra properties that are added by the ADO *after* you connect. it's the default properties for the specific provider you use (`SQLOLEDB.1`). The same properties will be set in all your other applications if you use the exact connection string or `UDL` file (with a common provider). 
ADO connections to SQL Server are pooled by default.

You can simply set e.g.

```
MyConnection.ConnectionString := 'FILE NAME=c:\my_shared_path\shared.udl';
MyConnection.Open;
```

A good place to hold a shared connection object (`TADOConnection`) is in a shared Data Module for the entire application. 
Open it in the data module or the main form `OnCreate` event.
The connection is automatically closed once the `TADOConnection` is destroyed.

Comment: Can you please answer third question? are there any performance issues or burden over Database server? coz i am not closing the connection till i close the application? so if 100 users are using that applications there will be 100 connections open. so for 5 Applications 5* 100 users = 500 opened connections

Comment: By default SQL server allows a maximum of 32,767 user connections. most of the time in "sleeping" state. is that enough for you?

Comment: so there wont be any performance issues or burden on server. Thank you.